# How to access results of powershell.exe command in the PowerShell session?

Tags: powershell

I am trying to start PowerShell  from CMD by using this command.

```
powershell.exe -NoProfile -NoExit -command "& {$someVar = 'test'}"
```

How do I access the variable **someVar** in the PowerShell. MSDN says that "The results of the script are returned to the parent shell as deserialized XML objects, not live objects." .

Comment: "I am trying to start PowerShell from CMD" - why?

Comment: What is the rest of your code doing? A single line of code without any further context isn't much help to us.

Comment: Hello Bill, James : We have an application that makes an REST call to identity management system and gets some values (Example: Username, password to some application based on the eligibility of the user running the application). We are trying to have an option so that users, especially someone like an admin can click on a button that starts a  PowerShell session with all the variables already available.

Comment: Here is the sample code I wrote. I am really new to PowerShell.

    `Process compiler = new Process();
    compiler.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
    compiler.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    compiler.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
    compiler.Start();
   compiler.StandardInput.WriteLine(String.Format(@"powershell -
   NoProfile -NoExit -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -command ". {$username 
   = {0}}" "), GetFromApi());`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`& {$someVar = 'test'}"` executes the scriptblock in a local scope which is deleted when it's done executing the scriptblock.

You need to create the variable in the `$global`-scope (session-wide)

```
CMD> powershell.exe -NoProfile -NoExit -command "& {$global:someVar = 'test'}"

PS> $someVar
test
```

or use dot-sourcing `. <script/scriptblock>` to excecute the scriptblock, which runs everything in the current scope (session in this case)

```
CMD> powershell.exe -NoProfile -NoExit -command ". {$someVar = 'test'}"

PS> $someVar
test
```

Read more about variables scopes [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes)

Comment: Thank you Frode F. I am really new to PowerShell so I was not aware that these commands run in the local scope. I will go read the scopes now. Thanks again.